# Current Regulator IC/Transistor

Tags: constant-current, current-limiting

Can anyone suggest a Current Regulator that can bring down 2A to 40mA... I'll be needing 40mA to power my arduino... I'm not that keen in electronics so pls use simple terms in explaining things to me ...THANKS =)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to "bring down 2A to 40mA". Providing the voltage is correct for the arduino, the arduino will take precisely the current it needs.

It's likely that the power source maximum current rating is 2A and this is confusing you.

Comment: My power supply is just a transformer with a full wave rectifier... I think that is safe if im using a switching power supply...but i don't have that right now

Comment: @AlyzhaOrejudos You need to ensure that the extremes of voltages that can be produced by your power supply are compatible with the target system.